# Is transcranial magnetic stimulation a medically proven treatment for major depressive disorder?

Tags: depression

Is TMS a legitimate treatment for major depressive disorder? What research has demonstrated this?

I see some evidence for its effectiveness, but I also see people flagging it as suspect or pseudoscience. Which is true?

Comment: What does your research show thus far?

Comment: Please try to not reply in comments but by making an [edit] so that your question contains all relevant information necessary to start research and/or to write an answer. Btw. Welcome to the site! Please take the [tour] and visit [help] and read [ask|.

Comment: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22579164